# Why after set mapping, index return nothing?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elk, logstash-jdbc

I am using Elasticsearch 7.12.0 , Logstash 7.12.0, Kibana 7.12.0 on Windows 10 x64. Logstash config file `logistics.conf`

```
input {
  jdbc {
    jdbc_driver_library => "D:\\tools\\postgresql-42.2.16.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "org.postgresql.Driver"
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/ld"
    jdbc_user => "xxxx"
    jdbc_password => "sEcrET"
    schedule => "*/5 * * * *"
    statement => "select * from inventory_item_report();"
    }
}

filter {
  uuid {
    target => "uuid"
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "http://localhost:9200"
    index => "localdist"
    document_id => "%{uuid}"
    doc_as_upsert => "true"
    }
}
```

Run logstash

```
logstash -f logistics.conf
```

If I don't set mapping explicit, the query

```
GET /localdist/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
```

return many result.

My mappings

```
POST localdist/_mapping
{
  
}

DELETE /localdist

PUT /localdist
{
  
}

POST /localdist
{
  
}

PUT localdist/_mapping
{
  "properties": {
    "unt_cost": {
      "type": "double"
    },
    "ii_typ": {
      "type": "keyword"
    },
    "qty_uom_id": {
      "type": "keyword"
    },
    "prod_id": {
      "type": "keyword"
    },
    "root_cat_id": {
      "type": "keyword"
    },
    "uom": {
      "type": "keyword"
    },
    "product_name": {
      "type": "text"
    },
    "ii_id": {
      "type": "keyword"
    },
    "wght_uom_id": {
      "type": "keyword"
    },
    "iid_seq_id": {
      "type": "long"
    },
    "avai_diff": {
      "type": "double"
    },
    "invt_change_typ": {
      "type": "keyword"
    },
    "ccy": {
      "type": "keyword"
    },
    "exp_date": {
      "type": "date"
    },
    "req_amt": {
      "type": "text"
    },
    "pur_cost": {
      "type": "double"
    },
    "tot_pri": {
      "type": "long"
    },
    "own_pid": {
      "type": "keyword"
    },
    "doc_type": {
      "type": "keyword"
    },
    "ii_date": {
      "type": "date"
    },
    "fac_id": {
      "type": "keyword"
    },
    "shipment_type_id": {
      "type": "keyword"
    },
    "lot_id": {
      "type": "keyword"
    },
    "phy_invt_id": {
      "type": "keyword"
    },
    "facility_name": {
      "type": "text"
    },
    "amt_ohand_diff": {
      "type": "double"
    },
    "reason_id": {
      "type": "keyword"
    },
    "cat_id": {
      "type": "keyword"
    },
    "qty_ohand_diff": {
      "type": "double"
    },
    "@timestamp": {
      "type": "date"
    }
  }
}
```

run query

```
GET /localdist/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
```

return nothing.

How to fix it, how to make explicit mappings works correctly?

Comment: What is POST mapping doing for you?

Comment: I use Logstash JDBC put index to Elasticsearch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got you right, you are indexing via logstash. Elastic then create the index if missing, indexes the documents, and tries to guess the mapping for your documents based on the very first documents.

TL;DR: You are DELETING your index containing the data by yourself.

With

```
DELETE /localdist
```

you are deleting the whole index including all data. After that, by issuing

```
PUT /localdist
{
  
}
```

you are re-creating the previously deleted index which is empty again. And at the end, you are setting the index mapping with

```
PUT localdist/_mapping
{
  "properties": {
    "unt_cost": {
      "type": "double"
    },
    "ii_typ": {
      "type": "keyword"
    },
    ...
```

Now, as you have an empty elastic index with a mapping set, start the logstash pipeline again. If your documents are matching the index mapping, the docs should start to appear very quickly.

Comment: If Logstash pipeline has 15 fields, I explicit declaring mapping with 5 fields, what happens with other 10 fields, Please tell me the behavior in this case.?

Comment: If the fields mapping is not defined yet, elastic will try an "educated guess" based on the field value: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-mapping.html

Comment: I have mistake in function sql, when it call once, the result of JDBC pipeline return nearly nothing.

Comment: Cool, glad to hear that! Have fun!